# Apache spark failing on distinct call

Tags: apache-spark

I have a simple Apache Spark script:

```java
import os.path as op
import re

def get_file(line):
    fn = re.search(r'open\(\"(.*)\"\,', line)

    if fn is None:
        return ''

    filename = fn.group(1)
    return filename

data = sc.textFile(op.expanduser('files_folder/*'))
lineSet = data.map(lambda line: get_file(line))
print lineSet.count()
distinctLines = lineSet.distinct()
print distinctLines.count()
```

All it's supposed to do is return the set of distinct lines in all of the files. Unfortunately, it fails with this error:

```java
14/11/26 16:50:15 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 102.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 257)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

Anybody know what the issue is? A google search for this error returned a [rather unhelpful email exchange](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Caused-by-java-lang-OutOfMemoryError-unable-to-create-new-native-thread-td5379.html) about the thread limit.

Comment: What is the size of the file and how much memory you have allocated to executor.

Comment: The combined size of the files is 700 MB and each executor is given up to 2G.

Comment: Have you tried this a smaller dataset? Looks like you are just running out of memory.

Comment: Strange, it works now after I added a few files to my directory and I can't reproduce it anymore. It must have been a memory issue, which is kind of strange since nothing has changed between now and last night except the extra files.